# Combine two objects with the same keys

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I have two objects with the same keys:

```
{"key": "first_name", "value": "Jane"}
{"key": "last_name", "value": "Doe"}
```

and I want

```
{"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe"}
```

How can I do this in `jq`?

Comment: [from_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***jq*** solution (using **`reduce`** function):

```
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $o ({}; .[$o.key]=$o.value)' yourfile
```

Or even simpler using **`from_entries`** function:

```
jq -s 'from_entries' yourfile
```

The output (for both approaches):

```
{
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

---

- `--slurp/-s` - option, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once

Answer (score 0):

Below should work for you

```
jq 'map({(.key): .value}) | add' test.json
```

Outputs

```
{
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

PS: Answer taken from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/70